# Sony SmartWatch 2: need to change supportsLowPowerMode() at runtime

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have an app for the SW2 that has a user option for whether the app should use low-power mode (LPM). Which works fine. The problem is that the SW API only calls my app's supportsLowPowerMode() registration method once, when it first starts up. Meaning that if the user later changes the setting in my app, it won't take effect until the whole shebang restarts.

I've tried a few tricks (like killing my app's process) to force a reload, but nothing's worked so far. My last resort is telling the user that s/he needs to reboot the phone before this takes effect, but that's pretty hokey. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to try to change your response to `supportsLowPowerMode()` at runtime, but to start and stop your extension instead.

Basically, if your extension can *ever* support LPM, then it should be returning a value of `true` in `supportsLowPowerMode()`. If the extension's LPM usage can change, you handle that by simply doing different things in the `onActiveLowPowerModeChange()` handler. Specifically, if the user has chosen NOT to use LPM, you want a handler that looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onActiveLowPowerModeChange(boolean lowPowerModeOn) {
    super.onActiveLowPowerModeChange(lowPowerModeOn);

    if (lowPowerModeOn) {
        // User doesn't want to use LPM, so stop the app on the SW
        stopRequest();
    }
}
```

This has the effect of shutting down your extension when the device's backlight turns off, and it'll drop back to its default LPM watchface.

EDIT: I'm reopening this as I've found an unacceptable side effect to the above technique. If your app returns `false` to `supportsLowPowerMode()`, the SW2 will keep it running (but paused) in the background when the watch goes to sleep. This means that, when the user "wakes up" the SW2, your app will immediately reappear on screen. Calling `stopRequest()` (as in my code sample above) disrupts this behavior, requiring the user to reopen your app after awakening the SW2. I've not found any way around this; what's needed is a `pauseRequest()` instead, but the API doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to change this at runtime.  Let me double check with my team though just in case there is a way I don't know about.

Comment: Hmm. I thought I commented on this yesterday, but now it's gone. Followup question for you or the team: what's the recommended way to get the SW2 to reload the return value of supportsLowPowerMode()? Is there anything short of rebooting the phone which will trigger this? Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed that once the extension has set that low power mode is supported there is no way to change it at runtime without restarting the extension.  You should not have to reboot the phone though, just quit the extension and start it again.  Unfortunately quitting and then restarting is the only solution currently.

Comment: What do you mean by "quit the extension"? I've tried everything from a stopRequest() call up to killing my process at the Android system level, and nothing reliably works. It's like this value has been cached at the host end, and nothing short of a reboot will refresh that cache.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the response from someone on our team.  Methods in the Registration class are only called once by SmartConnect on the first time the extension is run.  After that, those values are cached in SmartConnect like you noticed.  The only way to clear that cache is to either reboot the phone or reinstall the extension.